# Websphere Liberty: How to specify log4j2 configuration location?

Tags: log4j2, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I'm trying to tell Websphere Liberty where is located my `log4j2.xml`file, but it isn't working.

In my file `jvm.options` I configure:

```
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:///${server.config.dir}/log4j2.xml
```

but it looks like Liberty does not understand the variable ${server.config.dir} in the jvm.options file. The file is in the same directory of the `server.xml` file.

How would I specify the log4j2.xml location for Liberty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be possible by creating a Library entry in your server.xml such as:

```
<library id="log4jLib">
   <folder dir="/opt/log4j2/config"/>
</library>
```

where the directory specified contains the log4j2 properties or xml file.

Then specify a classloader for your application like this:

```
<application id="test" name="test" type="ear" location="test.ear">
  <classloader commonLibraryRef="log4jLib" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `${server.config.dir}` variable is one of the Liberty built-in server config variables, these only apply within the server.xml (and included configurations).

When you run a Liberty server, the `user.dir` gets set to the same thing as `${server.config.dir}`, so you could just specify the relative path to your log4j2.xml file in jvm.options as:

```
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

For Liberty I do the following;
I have a jvm.options file containing:

```
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2.xml
```

I place both files (log4j2.xml and jvm.options) in the server config.
I.e where tour server.xml etc is placed:

```
usr/servers/<myserver>:
 server.xml
 jvm.options
 log4j2.xml
```

That does the trick for me.

Comment: How to dynamically specify the file location? for spring boot I use `mvn spring-boot:run -Dlogging.config=/path/to/log4j2-dev.xml`,  how about liberty, I tried `mvn liberty -Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2-dev.xml`  but not work

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways of configuring log4j in WebSphere. Aside from the library entries method mentioned by [pseudonym](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3936969/pseudonym), you can simply drop the log4j2 configuration file to the global library directory at

**wlp/usr/servers//lib/global**

If there are files present in above location at the time an application is started, and that application does not have a classloader element configured, the application uses these libraries. If a class loader configuration is present, these libraries are not used unless the global library is explicitly referenced.

You can find more details about the global libraries in this link

[WebSphere Liberty Shared Libraries](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/cwlp_sharedlibrary.html)